# Trouble connecting express api to nuxt app and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, nuxt.js, digital-ocean

It's been seriously 10 days since i'm trying to deploy my web app online. i've gone back and forth between heroku and digital ocean. nothing solved. i've asked questions here all i get is a long post with technical terms i' not able to understand. Here's my problem :
i have a nuxt app with express.js in the backend and mongodb as the database. At first i had trouble with configuring host and port for my nuxt app. once i fixed it, anoither problem appeared : i'm not receiving data from the database. i don't if it's something related to database connection or with the express api configuration.

here's my nuxt config

```js
export default {
    ssr: false,
    head: {
        titleTemplate: 'Lokazz',
        title: 'Lokazz',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            {
                name: 'viewport',
                content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'
            },
            {
                hid: 'description',
                name: 'description',
                content:
                    'Lokazz'
            }
        ],
        link: [
            {
                rel: 'stylesheet',
                href:
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500,600,700&amp;amp;subset=latin-ext'
            }
        ]
    },

    css: [
        'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css',
        '~/static/fonts/Linearicons/Font/demo-files/demo.css',
        '~/static/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        '~/static/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        '~/assets/scss/style.scss'
    ],

    plugins: [
        { src: '~plugins/vueliate.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/swiper-plugin.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-notification.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/axios.js'},
        { src: '~/plugins/lazyLoad.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/mask.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/toastr.js', ssr: false },
    ],


    buildModules: [
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
        '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
        'cookie-universal-nuxt'
    ],

    styleResources: {
        scss: './assets/scss/env.scss'
    },

    modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios', 'nuxt-i18n','vue-sweetalert2/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/auth-next', "bootstrap-vue/nuxt"],
    bootstrapVue: {
        bootstrapCSS: false, // here you can disable automatic bootstrapCSS in case you are loading it yourself using sass
        bootstrapVueCSS: false, // CSS that is specific to bootstrapVue components can also be disabled. That way you won't load css for modules that you don't use
       
    },

    i18n: {
        locales: [
            { code: 'en', file: 'en.json' },
        ],
        strategy: 'no_prefix',
        fallbackLocale: 'en',
        lazy: true,
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        langDir: 'lang/locales/'
    },

    router: {
        linkActiveClass: '',
        linkExactActiveClass: 'active',
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080, // default: 3000
        host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
    },
    auth: {
        strategies: {
          local: {
            token: {
              property: "token",
              global: true,
            },
            redirect: {
                "login": "/account/login",
                "logout": "/",
                "home": "/page/ajouter-produit",
                "callback": false
            },
            endpoints: {
              login: { url: "/login", method: "post" },
              logout: false, //  we don't have an endpoint for our logout in our API and we just remove the token from localstorage
              user:false
            }
          }
        }
      },
};
```

here's my package.json

```json
{
    "name": "martfury_vue",
    "version": "1.3.0",
    "description": "Martfury - Multi-purpose Ecomerce template with vuejs",
    "author": "nouthemes",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nuxt",
        "build": "nuxt build",
        "start": "nuxt start",
        "generate": "nuxt generate"
    },
    "config": {
        "nuxt": {
          "host": "0.0.0.0",
          "port": "8080"
        }
    },
}
```

here's my repository.js file

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';

const token = Cookies.get('id_token');
const baseDomain = 'https://lokazzfullapp-8t7ec.ondigitalocean.app';


export const customHeaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json'
};

export const baseUrl = `${baseDomain}`;

export default axios.create({
    baseUrl,
    headers: customHeaders
});

export const serializeQuery = query => {
    return Object.keys(query)
        .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(query[key])}`)
        .join('&');
};
```

an example of an api call i make locally that works without a problem :

```js
import Repository, { serializeQuery } from '~/repositories/Repository.js';
import { baseUrl } from '~/repositories/Repository';
import axios from 'axios'
const url = baseUrl;

export const actions = {
    async getProducts({ commit }, payload) {
        const reponse = await axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                commit('setProducts', response.data);
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => ({ error: JSON.stringify(error) }));
        return reponse;
    },
}
```

here's my index.js (express file)

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors');
//const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/lokazz'
const url = 'mongodb+srv://lokazz:zaki123456@cluster0.hsd8d.mongodb.net/lokazz?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const con = mongoose.connection

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}).then(()=>{
    const app = express();

    // middlleware
    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cors());

    //products routes 
    const products = require('./product/product.router');
    app.use('/', products)
    //users routes
    const users = require('./user/user.router');
    app.use('/', users)
    const port =  process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
    }).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));


con.on('open', () => {
    console.log('connected...')
})
```

My directory structure
[image]

the error i get after the api request, meaning it's not receving any data.

```
ebd1ecd.js:2 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')
    at f.<anonymous> (c88240c.js:1)
    at f.t._render (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at f.r (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at wn.get (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at new wn (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at t (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at f.In.$mount (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at init (ebd1ecd.js:2)
    at ebd1ecd.js:2
    at v (ebd1ecd.js:2)
```

idk if it's a problem with mongodb connection cluster or the api call.

Comment: `ssr: false` is outdated, use `mode: client`. You should not do this `commit('setProducts', response.data);`. Use a Vuex action and please keep `async/await` all the way (without any `.then` in the middle). `idk if it's a problem with mongodb connection cluster or the api call`, you know where to start so. Also, from where is this screenshot? Do you have your backend and frontend in the same place? Did you tried fetching the data with Postman? You should be the one to narrow down the issue. Stackoverflow is not a coding service where you can dump your whole codebase.

Comment: @kissu yes i have the backend and front in the sane place :). also  this screenshot is from my directory. i tried the api call with postman and insomnia. everything works perfectly :)

Comment: So, you do have both apps running on Digitalocean? How do you launch both your Node and Nuxt app at the same time? Why not splitting them? Having an API baked into a frontend app is not giving you anything at all since they are not tied anyhow.